# dart onscreen Keyboard events

Tags: dart, angular-dart, dart-html

i want to make an onscreen Keyboard in dart with angular.js.
If one letter is pressed it should be on the html site.

How does it work?

This is what i´ve got in the index.html:

```dart
<button on-click="einsController.generateName()"id="z" class="button">Z</button>
<button on-click="einsController.generateName()"id="u" class="button">U</button>
<button on-click="einsController.generateName()"id="i" class="button">I</button>
<button on-click="einsController.generateName()"id="o" class="button">O</button>
<button on-click="einsController.generateName()"id="p" class="button">P</button>
<button on-click="einsController.generateName()"id="a" class="button">A</button>
<button on-click="einsController.generateName()"id="s" class="button">S</button>
<button on-click="einsController.generateName()"id="d" class="button">D</button>
<button on-click="einsController.generateName()"id="f" class="button">F</button>
<button on-click="einsController.generateName()"id="g" class="button">G</button>
<button on-click="einsController.generateName()"id="h" class="button">H</button>
<button on-click="einsController.generateName()"id="j" class="button">J</button>
<button on-click="einsController.generateName()"id="k" class="button">K</button>
<button on-click="einsController.generateName()"id="l" class="button">L</button>
<button on-click="einsController.generateName()"id="y" class="button">Y</button>
<button on-click="einsController.generateName()"id="x" class="button">X</button>
<button on-click="einsController.generateName()"id="c" class="button">C</button>
<button on-click="einsController.generateName()"id="v" class="button">V</button>
<button on-click="einsController.generateName()"id="b" class="button">B</button>
<button on-click="einsController.generateName()"id="n" class="button">N</button>
<button on-click="einsController.increment()"id="m" class="button">M</button>
```

This is where the letter shall appear:

```dart
   <span id="badgeName">{{einsController.name}}  </span>
```

this is the function in the dart File:

```dart
  String name = '';

    void generateName() {
     name = "Q"; 
}
```

I still don´t get it. I think I need to change something in the method of generateName().

I want an onScreenKeyboard something like this http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-a-keyboard-with-css-and-jquery--net-5774

Only that it I need to use dart Code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ng-click` directive should be on the button where you click not on the tag where you want to show the result.

You don't need your `query('#letter_A').onClick.listen(...` when you use `ng-click` they have similar functionality.

You need to place the controller `keyboard` so that your buttons and the `<div>` where you want to show the output are within the tag where the controller is applied.

Try it and if it doesn't work update your question with the new code and I'll take another look.

Comment: I don´get it . I tried some other tutorials but i won´t work for me. All I want is that if i click the button "A" A appears and if I click "B" B appears in a field.

Comment: I published a complete working example to https://github.com/bwu-dart/angular_playground/tree/master/web/keyboard I build it a bit differently. `keyboard` is a component but without the `textarea`. If you add the `textarea` as children (like in my example) the layout should be similar to the original example. For this `textarea` needs to have the `id="write"`. If you want to put the `textarea` somewhere else this id isn't necessary. The values are bount to a controller (`ng-controller="text-ctrl") I added in `index.dart`. This is necessary for the `keyboard` and the `textarea` to connect them.

Comment: Some examples in this are outdated and show errors in DartEditor. The keyboard example works and is tested with Angular 0.10.0.